# how to create click of button in PYQT

Tags: button, click, pyqt, save

I've been having some trouble with create click of buttons in PyQT.
when i create click of button as below , this picture can't save

```
        cv.SetImageROI(image, (pt1[0],pt1[1],pt2[0] - pt1[0],int((pt2[1] - pt1[1]) * 1)))
        if self.Button.click():
            cv.SaveImage('example.jpg', image)

    cv.ResetImageROI(image)
```

Comment: You need to study about `signals and slots` in PyQt.
http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html

Answer (score 8):

The problem in your code is that you are performing a programmatic click on the button calling `QPushButton.click` on the line `if self.Button.click():`, what you need to do is to connect the signal `QPushButton.clicked` to a proper slot on your code. Singals and Slots is the way Qt handle some significant events that may occur on the object. Here I'll drop you an example, hope it helps:

```
import PyQt4.QtGui as gui

#handler for the signal aka slot
def onClick(checked):
    print checked #<- only used if the button is checkeable
    print 'clicked'

app = gui.QApplication([])

button = gui.QPushButton()
button.setText('Click me!')

#connect the signal 'clicked' to the slot 'onClick'
button.clicked.connect(onClick)

#perform a programmatic click
button.click()

button.show()
app.exec_()
```

Note: To understand the underlying behavior read the docs of Qt/PyQt.